# Files not uploading completely from python cgi

Tags: python, forms, file, upload, cgi

I have a uploading app that uploads from html.
it works completely fine from localhost, but when my friends try to upload something only 1 percent of that file is only uploaded which is a huge problem for me.
Server is running on python http.server from command line with --cgi

CGI:

```
import uuid
import os 
import cgi, cgitb
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
fileitem = form.getvalue("filename")
uuid134 = str(uuid.uuid4())
open( "uploads/" + uuid134 + ".bytes", "wb").write(fileitem)
open("uploads/" + uuid134 + ".form" , "w").write(str(form))
```

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> <title>Upload file</title> 
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport">
</head>
<body> 
   <form enctype = "multipart/form-data" action = "cgi-bin/python_script.py" method = "post"> 
   <label for="upload"><input type = "file" name = "filename" /></label>
   <label for="submit"><input type = "submit" value = "Upload" /></label>
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I have been trying to fix this problem for many ages but failed.

I have used tunneling service (didn't work), port forwarded (also didn't work), localhost (worked and uploaded whole file)

Comment: first you could run it in console and observer if you get any error mesage when someone try to upload file. And if you get error message then you should show it in question (not comment) as text (not image)

Comment: how big file it was uploaded. I don't know if `http.server` has any limitation but real web servers usualy have some limit for uploads - for security reasons.

Comment: `CGI` is very old technology and probably nobody use it - maybe you should try something modern - web frameworks like `Flask`, `Bottle`, `Django`

Comment: if you want only upload files then maybe you should rather install FTP server - ie. [proftd](http://www.proftpd.org/) (on Linux) or [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)

Comment: the file is around 100kb big in size, and im uncomfortable using flask, bottle or django

Comment: if you don't get any error message when friend uploads file then we can't say what can be problem. Problem can be anything - even friend's computer.

Comment: well all my friends have the problem

Comment: without any error message we don't know what really makes problem. Code doesn't gives error message so It seems code is OK. So maybe problem makes antyvirus on your computer, or antyvirus on your friends computers. Or maybe problem makes router of your Internet Provider - but we can't access it and change its settings. Without errors or other messages we don't have clue and we can't help.